# C Function for name and 2 doubles, looped 5 times and passed by reference

Tags: c, function, methods, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am at my wit's end, which is to say that I'm confused on what I'm confused on. Assignment for my CS36 class.

We are supposed to create a simple payroll program in C, where we use a method for input 5 different employee names, hours worked and hourly rate all in one method. Within that method we are supposed to use parameter passing and pass by reference. Then use another method to calculate the gross, base and overtime pay, pass by reference. Then use another method that calculates tax, taking as input the gross pay, returning the tax owed. And then we print the details of all 5.

I'm having an issue even in the first part. When I have the name&hours input in main, I believe there is not much of an issue. However when I put these inputs in their own function that I call in main, the exe just hangs after I input the name.

It's been close to 3 hours of me reading on functions, parameters, and passing by reference and yet I'm still quite mystified. There's most likely something I'm not getting. I'll tackle the hurdle of the other functions once I cross that bridge.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define size 5

void inputNameRateHours(char name, double rate, double hours);
double computeGross(double hoursworked, double hourlyrate);
//double computeOvertime(double hoursworked, double overtimerate)
//double computeTax(double gross);
//double computeNet(double gross, double tax);
//double totalpaidtoallemployees(double gross[size]);
//void printmethod(double *totalpaidtoallemployees);

int main()
{
    char name=0;
    double hours = 0, rate = 0,  gross = 0, tax = .2, totalpaidtoallemployees = 0;
    inputNameRateHours(name, rate, hours);
    printf("The name %s, the rate %d, the hours%f", &name, &rate, &hours);
    gross= computeGross(hours, rate);
    printf("");
    //computeTax(gross);
    //computeNet(gross, tax);
    //totalpaidtoallemployees*(gross);


    return 0;

}
void inputNameRateHours(char *name, double *rate, double *hours) {
    int loopcount;
    for (loopcount = 0; loopcount < size; loopcount++) 
    {
        printf("Employee Name:");
        scanf("\n %s \n", &name);
        if (strcmp(name, "-1") == 0)
            break;
        printf("\n Enter hourly rate:");
        scanf("%d", &rate);
        if ((rate = -1) == 0)
            break;
        printf("\n Enter hours worked:");
        scanf("%d", &hours);
        if ((hours = -1) == 0)
            break;
    }
}
double computeGross(double hours, double rate) {
    if (hours <= 40)
        return hours*rate;
    else if (hours > 40)
        printf("This employee worked overtime.");
}
```

Comment: Prototype given before main and function head implemented after main are different for `inputNameRateHours()`. Prototype before with direct parameters, implemented after with pointers to parameters. Is that typos when posting here? If not, what happens if you fix that?

Comment: Please explain the purpose of `if ((rate = -1) == 0)`.

Comment: Yeah that was me tinkering trying what little I knew to make it work. Once they all match, it still hangs after I input name. Is it the new line \n escape sequence in the scanf that screws me?

Comment: Pleae compile with strict warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall` and handle all warnings.

Comment: The =-1 is so that if the input is -1 in name or hours or rate, it breaks a loop and will go to output of all data

Comment: k I'll go ahead and do that with strict warnings. I always put that because I'm lazy with scanf, thanks for the heads up

Comment: The `= -1` is an assignment.

Comment: Do not compare floats for equality.

Comment: Ok, That seemed to be the issue. Now I can move on to my next issue. I'll mark as solved.

Comment: I am so new to stackoverflow and programming in general, I literally don't know where to mark as answered.

Comment: If that is sufficient and you have fixed everything else in your code already, my respect... Shall I make an answer of my first comment? Only then you can accept it.

Comment: sure, yes please. danke schoene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype given before main and function head implemented after main are different for `inputNameRateHours(...)`.
Prototype before with direct parameters, implemented after with pointers to parameters.

I recommend to compile with strict warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall`.

As far as I can tell you will have to fix:

- prototype mistake as mentioned above
- missing include
- space for name
- improve scanf
- missing return in second function
- several cases of mismatching indirection/dereferencing (`&/*`)
- assignment inside comparison
- floating point identity comparison
- format specifiers in printf

You indicated that you fixed already to your satisfaction, so I will leave it at that;
which matches StackOverflow recommendation for homework/assignments.
Good luck.

Comment: Exactly. Now that I got over my hurdle, I'll try to figure the rest of my issues myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your problem.

Declare the function BEFORE main. Then no prototype (that doesn't match) is necessary. Look up 'forward referencing'.

Extra points: explain why having a different prototype before main is causing the problem.